# Java string .length() X does not fit into DB2 varchar(X)

Tags: java, character-encoding, size, varchar, string-length

I observed one issue that, I am trying to save a record in DB2 database with fields having length check in Java code. I have kept length check exactly equal to database varchar limit. And trying to save but getting SQL Exception DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.57.82;

Then I reduced the length (truncated) the length smaller than the database size. Truncated to substring (0, 900) apprx for varchar(1000).

Please let me what could be the reason of the same. Is it related to character encoding?
How it needs to be handled?

What is default character encoding applied to String (input from request parameter of a text area field) and corresponding no. of bytes?

Comment: There definitely could be a character encoding issue.  Characters in java are actually implemented as code points.  Some characters require two code points to be accurately depicted.  Meaning that even though a String might only show a length of 1000 it might actually contain 2000 code points.

Comment: [It seems](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.java.doc%2Fdoc%2Frjvjdata.htm) that you may need up to 3 times the length of your string.

Answer (score 4):

DB2 counts string length in bytes, not characters. The max length of a string you can store can therefore be a lot shorter than the size given for varchar.

Unfortunately the only way to truncate a string to a number of bytes is to encode it as bytes, truncating, and reconstructing the string. From what you say it sounds like a variable length encoding such as UTF-8 is being used. The difficult part is not producing an invalid character at the end, and the way to do that is using the NIO charset API:

```
import java.nio.*;
...
CharBuffer in = CharBuffer.wrap(stringToTruncate);
ByteBuffer out = ByteBuffer.allocate(maxLength);
Charset db2charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
CharsetEncoder db2encoder = db2charset.newEncoder();
db2encoder.encode(in, out, true);
out.flip();
return db2charset.decode(out).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving the solutions. This is a very common check for all applications. So is this the best practice to be applied through out all applications development? I would like to know the expert's opinion on this :)

Comment: I wouldn't call myself an expert by I think it should be very rare to have to mangle user data to make it fit the database; rather the database should serve the user. I've had to do this once though, to store error messages read from a log file, where the longest messages could include stack traces and other lengthy debug information, but the first 200 characters are enough for the users most of the time and if they need to see more they can open the original file